# rails, friendly_id, devise username not showing slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise, slug, friendly-id

i feel like i am missing something obvious, but hopefully someone can help me out quickly.

i am trying to create a friendly_id slug for my User Model (using Devise). Here is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :username, :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false},
  :format => { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/ }

end
```

In my UserController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

When I load up the show method in my browser, it still has localhost:3000/user/3 - it does not show the slug. I know I have everything working because I have the same code in my Post Model and it works perfectly. Is there something I am missing with the User Validation / Devise that is causing it not to work?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is slug not saved. I think you are trying to find a legacy record which is saved before you initialized the friendly_id. But although you can generate slug and generate friendly-id for your record. Here is the process.

```
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
   new_record? || slug.nil? || slug.blank? # you can add more condition here
end
```

after adding this method, just trying save all the record again. Friendly will call the method and will update the slug if condition matched you defined inside that block.

```
User.find_each(&:save!)
```

In your view file write the url like:

```
<%= link_to "USER", current_user %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "USER", user_path(current_user.to_param) %>
```

Please also make sure you don't have the username blank. If there is any chance that username can be blank you can use a dynamic method where you can set the column conditionally to use for generating slug. I think that should be all!
Thank you!

Comment: Hi Rubyrider - thanks for your reply! I tried what you suggested, but it still not displaying the slug in the URL. In fact, I took a lot in the User table, and the slug column is populated so it is definitely saving. In fact, if I type in the slug into the URL, it works. (ex. localhost:3000/user/bobsmith) - it is only when I click the link from the page, it will still display the ID. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh I understand then. So how you define your url? Can you give an example? so I can help? I think I understand your problem.

Comment: Sure, thanks! - in my show method view, one of my main user links is: <%= link_to "USER", user_path(current_user.id) %> - this link will go to localhost:3000/user/3

Comment: Here is the wrong my friend :) Let me specify this in my answer okey?

Comment: Just check my answer now :) You were directly calling id attributes which will only give you the id value. But rails generate url by calling to_param on the object to generate the id. So I guess now all should work! Happy coding!